# Can multiple files be imported with the /s3/import robot

Tags: transloadit

The docs indicate that the 'url' parameter of the /http/import robot allows for an array of urls that can be imported by the relevant step.  In the docs, the /s3/import robot's 'path' parameter only seems to accept a single path in a step.  Is there any way to import multiple s3 documents in a step?

Answer (score 0):

(speaking as a Transloadit co-founder) Currently that's not possible, but a feature request has been filed and we expect to ship this before the end of the month (October 2014).